# What is the best way to verify controller arguments?

Tags: 8, routes, page-controller

For example, I have a path on my site.

Let it be www.mysite.com/year/{year}/month/{month}/day/{day}

Could you clarify me, what is the best way to avoid getting of wrong arguments, such as year/3000/month/15/day/32 ?

Should I verify them inside the function called with the controller? Or is there a separated function or method to verify them, which wouldn't let invoke the controller function in case of wrong arguments?

Comment: I suppose [routing requirements](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#adding-wildcard-requirements) would be an option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here my working example:

**.routing.yml**

```
forcontu_pages.calculator:
  path: '/forcontu/pages/calculator/{num1}/{num2}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\forcontu_pages\Controller\ForcontuPagesController::calculator'
    num1: 20
    num2: 10
    _title: 'Calculator Page'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access calculator'
    _custom_access:  '\Drupal\forcontu_pages\Controller\ForcontuPagesController::access'
```

**ForcontuPagesController.php**

```
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;
...
  public function access(AccountInterface $account, $num1, $num2) {
    // Check permissions and combine that with any custom access checking needed. Pass forward
    // parameters from the route and/or request as needed.
    return AccessResult::allowedIf($num1 > $num2);
  }
...
```

I just verify that $num1 is greater than $num2, but you can add your other params and your validations.

See that you can add more params:

> The access method arguments are resolved similar to [normal](https://www.drupal.org/node/2310425)
>   routing. The following arguments are optionally available; they will
>   be populated if they are properly type hinted:
>
> - The slugs, like with normal routing.
> - \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request
> - \Symfony\Component\Routing\Route $route
> - \Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatch $route_match
> - \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxy $account

***Read***: [What is a slug?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19335215/3653989)

Reference:
[Access checking on routes](https://www.drupal.org/node/2122195)

Comment: @4k4 This is the way that I found

Comment: Great answer, also nice reference for slug.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what is expected to happen if the parameters are wrong, if it should return a page not found you can define constraints using regular expressions to validate the parameters in the route definition:

```
example.user
  path: '/example/{name}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\example\Controller\ExampleController::content'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
    name: '[a-zA-Z]+'
```

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/parameters-values-validation-in-routes

Comment: Here is an example of validation using the regular expressions, but I need valudation using a function which returns true or false.

Comment: This is a custom access https://www.drupal.org/node/2122195, which gets the same route arguments as the controller.

Comment: @4k4 I can't  get the point on how to use $request

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer, the argument has to be type hinted `public function access(Request $request)` and the use statement `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;`.

Comment: @4k4 yes I tried this   public function access(AccountInterface $account, Request $request) { but it doens't works, can you share a working example?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer, I found this example http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Access/CsrfRequestHeaderAccessCheck.php

Comment: @4k4 Yes I have the same code, I searched too, the problems seems the comunication between the routing file and the access method, I have this error: `::access" requires a value for the "$request" argument`. And I only add this to my routing file:     `_custom_access:  '\Drupal\forcontu_pages\Controller\ForcontuPagesController::access'`

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer, yes this is probably connected to the routing file. If you have route slugs it is possible you need to include them also.

Comment: @4k4 I have the answer :-) the problem was that I don't had get the point with what are slugs :-O (I'm not an english native)

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer, english is also not my first language. Just looked in the dictionary, this word can mean anything ;-)